# Algorithm for summing large number of very large numbers (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve [Problem 13 @ Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13) and I am looking for a good algorithm to do *addition* and output the answer for very large numbers. First, I convert the digits of the numbers to elements of a matrix(100 x 50). This is the algorithm I came up with:

```
unsigned long long int sum=0, carry_over=0;
for(int j=49; j>=0; j--)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        sum+=num[i][j];
    sum+=carry_over;
    carry_over=sum/10;
    cout<<sum%10;
    sum=0;
}
cout<<carry_over;
```

Now, the output will have reversed digits, starting with the units place digit and ending up in the first digit of the sum. This is easily reversed, manually.

I want to know if this is a good algorithm, considering accuracy and speed. Please suggest corrections to better it.

Comment: The better way is to use the full range of each "digit," so for example if you have a 64 bit computer you should use `uint64_t` for each digit and store the full range in each, instead of just 0 to 10 (which wastes space).

Comment: Why do you start adding up the last digits in each number?   [That question  is a hint, by the way].

Comment: @Peter I didn't get the hint. What else to do other than adding up last digits initially?

Comment: Can you be smarter about what digits you add up?   Are there circumstances in which the sum of the 100 last digits won't propagate/carry and affect the sum of the nth digit?    Consider upper bounds on the sum of a given digit.

Comment: as long as there are carry overs it will propagate

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is already optimal.

Your algorithm has a time complexity of `O(m*n)`, where `m` is the number of digits in each number (50) and `n` is the number of numbers (100), and that's the amount of digits you have in the input.  It is easy to see that you have to read *all* the digits from the input in order to output the correct answer, so you have to read at least `m*n` digits, giving a time complexity of `O(m*n)` *just* for reading the input.  Hence, the time complexity of your algorithm cannot be less than that, so your `O(m*n)` algorithm is optimal.

If, somehow, you already had the input data in RAM (and in a suitable format), you could consider some other optimizations.

Consideration of address size:

Modern computers have an address size of 32 or 64 bits, meaning that they can do addition on 32 or 64 bits in one operation.  64 bits is around 18 decimal digits, so 3 64-bit integers are all that is required to store each integer, and consequently the time complexity of addition will be reduced from `m=50` to `m=3`, making the summation an order of magnitude faster.

Consideration of parallel processing:

Modern computers can run multiple threads in parallel.  The solution to this problem is easily parallelizable.  If your machine is able to run 2 threads simultaneously, you could sum the first 50 numbers using the first thread, and the second 50 using the second thread.  After both sums are complete (in roughly half the time required if everything was computed on a single thread), you simply sum the two sub-results.